# Java generic неизвестного типа

Tags: java, generics

снова непонятки с генериками

Имеется некий интерфейс.
Он будет генерировать строку, причем генерация очень сильно зависит от его параметра `T`, также он будет предоставлять класс своего генерика

```
public interface SomeStringGenerator<T> {
    public String generate(T param);

    public Class<T> getTypeClass();
}
```

У него есть несколько различных реализаций, возможно будет больше, в общем обобщить T здесь совершенно невозможно.

Теперь есть какой-то класс, который будет работать с этим генератором, допустим будет составлять динамическую красивую страничку текста для пользователя. (Возможно пример не очень применяется на практике, но это только пример)

```
public class SomePageConsumer {
    private final Collection<SomeStringGenerator<?>> generators;
    private final SomeClass someObject;

    public String generateFormattedPage() {
       for (SomeStringGenerator<?> generator : generators) {
           if (someObject.getClass().isAssignableFrom(generator.getDataClass())){
               generator.generate(generator.getTypeClass().cast(someObject)); //compile error
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Собственно код позволяет предоставить все необходимые объекты для генераторов, но вот генераторы не хотят их принимать.
Не очень понимаю почему компилятор ругается, ведь используется явное преобразование обьектов к требуемому типу.

Comment: Я бы тоже не принял и эррорничал - объявлено `getTypeClass()`, а вызывается `getDataClass()`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо поправил. Писал здесь от руки чтобы лишнего не было т.к. в реалии классы гораздо больше

Comment: Проблема в том (и компилятор это в сообщении показывает), что у `generator` тип "SomeStringGenerator с параметром неизвестного типа", а `generator.getTypeClass()` возвращает класс с параметром неизвестного типа. Вот только компилятор никак не знает, что это один и то же неизвестный тип. `SomeStringGenerator<T>.generate` может принят параметр типа T. А вот `SomeStringGenerator<?>.generate` вообще вызывать нельзя (кроме как с параметром `null`), так как неизвестно, какой тип параметра нужно передавать. Это буквально "неизвестный тип". Нужно заменить знаки вопроса на `Object` .

Comment: @RomanKonoval так, окей, получается компилятор не может осознать что локально в пределах одного конкретного объекта, который параметризирован пусть и не известным параметром, но одинаковым для обоих методов откуда следует, что технически все будет работать в случае вызова данного кода?

Comment: Указывая `?` вы сами говорите компилятору, что типы не обязательно одинаковы. Это так если бы вы указали `List<Integer>` и `List<String>`. Тут типы разные, но известно какие. А со знаком вопроса, типы разные, но неизвестно какие. `откуда следует` - не следует, компилятор даже не дает скомпилировать, не то что запустить.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я просто не понимаю одного момента.  
например `Map<String, List<?>> map`  
`map.put("strings", new ArrayList<String>());`  
`map.put("ints", new ArrayList<Integer>());`  
В самой мапе типы листов не определны, но когда мы полуаем конкретный лист, его тип вполне конкретен, внутри него самого нет ни одного метода, который имел бы другую типизацию, нежели его соседи.
Здесь получается также, внутри одного объекта тип `T` неизменен. И в целом мне не важно какой он, я просто проверяю класс и работаю.
Получается компилятор не видит такой связи? или все-же я что-то делаю не так?